# Rails 5 CarrierWave Gem Works in Production But Not In Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

**Gem & Ruby Versions**

ruby '2.5.3', 'rails', '~> 5.2.1', 'carrierwave', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.3'

When I upload images in my local development environment, I receive no errors and no images are uploaded, but my same application in my production environment uploads images as it should.  I've double checked my settings and cannot see anything out of place and the fact that it works in production has me confused.

**image_uploader.rb**

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def default_url(*args)
    "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [500, 350]
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png pdf)
  end

end
```

**team.rb**

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  ...
end
```

**teams_controller.rb**

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
    ...
    def team_params
      params.require(:team).permit(:name, :title, :phone, :email, :bio, :image, :slug)
    end
end
```

**teams/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: team, local: true) do |form| %>
    ...
    <div class="form-group clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <%= form.file_field :image %>
        <div style="max-width: 300px">
          <% if @team.image_url %>
            <h5>Current Image</h5>
            <%= link_to @team do %>
              <figure>
                <%= image_tag @team.image_url %>
              </figure>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a initializer to check for errors during development:

```
config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.ignore_integrity_errors = false
  config.ignore_processing_errors = false
  config.ignore_download_errors = false
end
```

Comment: Looks like `ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed` -- I have a new MacBook and must have overlooked this install.  Thank you.  I'm accepting your answer because it led me to the solution.