# Rails Roolback Transaction When trying to upload images using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, dropzone.js, cloudinary

I am trying to upload images (file) using **carrierwave** to **cloudinary** for selecting the images using **dropzone_js** gem rails. tried many times it seems everything is fine but file is not uploading to cloudinary but the associated post is posting fine.

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qMpW.png)

[Controller file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ3sN.png)

[Views file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1Ztv.png)

Comment: I believe it is preferable to include your code in the body of your question instead of uploading pictures of your code. It's likely someone will want to try your code but it's unlikely anyone is willing to retype it from your pictures.

Comment: Yes Dan your right i will take care from next time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add the initializer that I pointed out here  [Rails 5 CarrierWave Gem Works in Production But Not In Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54056424/rails-5-carrierwave-gem-works-in-production-but-not-in-development/54056572#54056572) to be able to look the errors of carrierWave.

Comment: On a default config for a rails app the logs are on log/production.log, log/development.log, log/test.log